# Google Places, Swift Package Manager & M1 Mac issues

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uikit, apple-m1

I have students using Google Places AutoComplete with iOS UIKit and Swift. Students with M1 Macs still seem to not be able to use the simulator with this SDK and need to run on their devices (this is a problem because some students don’t have a decide and only develop on a Mac). Also, it seems the SDK doesn’t yet work with Swift Package Manager. Are there any solutions to these issues? This would definitely solve many student frustrations. Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you please share the error or issue screenshot here for more detail.... Bcz I have been fixing my Mac M1 Issues as well.

Comment: You can also ask your students to quit Xcode and Open Finder >  Application > Right click on Xcode > get Info > Check Icon for (Open Using Rosetta). It will fix most of the issues.

Comment: It's probably due to architecture difference between intel and M1. Why don't you share more specifics or just find more solutions in other stackoverflow answers?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for M1 Macs, which is to open Xcode with Rosetta enabled.

Find the Xcode app in Finder, and right-click it, then "Get Info", then tick "Open using Rosetta", then reopen Xcode.

It should not be too hard for students to set up. It can be setup just once and reused afterwards.

[image]